# Refreshing QgsMapCanvas after removing selected layer using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsmapcanvas

I am working on a PyQGIS (QGIS 3.10) application to overlay data on OpenStreetMap raster tiles.  I am adding a function that removes the most recently added layer from the project and refreshes the map.  It looks like this:

```
def rmv_layer(self):

    if not self.layer_names:

        print("No overlay to remove.")

    else:

        name = self.layer_names[-1].strip('[]')
        pstr = "Removing overlay: %s" % name
        print(pstr)
        layer = self.project.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
        self.project.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
        self.QMC.refreshAllLayers()
        self.layer_names.pop(-1)
        self.layers.pop(-1)

    return
```

where `self.layer_names` is a list that is updated with the layer name after one is added to the map canvas in a separate `add_overlay` class while the name of the removed layer and the layer itself is erased here using `pop`.  This code works fine the first time around.  However, when adding a new layer to the map canvas using the following code:

```
def add_layer(self):

   layer = QgsRasterLayer(self.new_raster,self.layer_title,"gdal")

   if ( layer.isValid() ):

        self.layer_names.extend(layer_title)
        self.project.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self.map_canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self.layers.insert(0,layer)
        self.map_canvas.setLayers(self.layers)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: index 1 has type 'QgsRasterLayer' but 'QgsMapLayer' is expected
```

I'm not sure what the root issue is since `QgsMapLayer` is the base class for `QgsRasterLayer`, `QgsVectorLayer`, etc.  The `self.layers` list is set up to where it always retains the base OpenStreetMap tiles in the 'registry'.  This error only occurs when I remove and refresh.  If I keep adding layers it's happy, and I have to refresh the map canvas otherwise the layer will still be displayed (e.g., commenting out `self.QMC.refreshAllLayers()` inherently does nothing).  This error also occurs without the `self.layers.pop(-1)` line in the first block.

Is there a better way to clear the most recent layer than this?

Answer (score 1):

The most recent layer added was to the front of the `QList<QgsMapLayer>` object, so it had to be:

```
self.layers.pop(0)
```

as it was still including the `QgsRasterLayer` info despite the feature being deleted.  Also moved the refresh statement to the end.  All works fine now.